# how to reload/refresh the component view forcefully?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

in my application I have a json object which is hardcoded. that values are bound with the input controls in the view. but if i changes the values of the json object during some events, then those changes values are not getting reflected in the view/input controls? how do i forcefully reload/refresh the view?

please look the component below. In that the values which i have assigned inside the constructor gets reflected in the view during the load of the component.
based on some events on the parent component, the method LoadExtractorQueueDetails() is called and the same variable this.sampleData is being reset with some other values.

ideally i expect these values to be reflected in the view? but this doesn't seem to happen? 
why it is not happening? how do i reload/refresh the views ?

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'extractorQueueDetails',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [CacheDataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: './HTML/Admin/ExtractorQueueDetails.html'
})
export class ExtractorQueueDetails {

    resultData: ExtractorQueueItem;
    sampleData: Sample;

    constructor() {
        console.log("ExtractorQueueDetails component is loaded");

        this.sampleData = { queueId: 123, name: "Krishnan" };
     }


    public LoadExtractorQueueDetails() {
        console.log("in LoadExtractorQueueDetails of ExtractorQueueDetails");

        this.sampleData = { queueId: 456, name: "Krishnan123" };

        console.log(this.sampleData);
    }
}
```

My HTML template is like below

```
   <input type="text" name="txtQueueID" class="form-control" id="txtQueueID" [(ngModel)]="sampleData.queueId" />
   <input type="text" name="Description"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sampleData.name" id="Description" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After reviewing your comment, outside of trying to use the ChangeDetectorRef object, I think there might be another possibility worth trying. If you want this to be driven off of a click event that is not inside your current component, you could register the component to listen for external click events, then see if the DOM object that was clicked on is a parent to the child component. If it is, then a component function would fire. Example [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/K2MgCpedfuSyCSlFEa58?p=preview).

In this example I assume your Child Component is just one DOM object in your Parent Component row. This leverages using the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html) object and the [HostListener](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-var.html) object. The meat of the event function code is filtering down to the event that you're looking for.

```
export class ChildComponent {
  private _exampeObject:IGeneric;
  @ViewChild('childcomponent') component: ElementRef;

  constructor(){
    this._exampleObject = {
      id:1,
      name:"Cyrus"
    };
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onClick(obj) {
    let incrementId = this._exampleObject.id + 1;
    let adjustName = this._exampleObject.name + incrementId.toString();
    if(this.component.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode === obj){
      this._exampleObject = {
        id: incrementId,
        name: adjustName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I think part of the problem is the approach to your problem. You mention that a "Parent" component is calling the "LoadExtractorQueueDetails()" method. This implies that the component you have shown is a "Child" component. This also means you are somehow calling the "Child" method from the "Parent", which is where things get weird. I guess you could do it but I think ChangeDetection is falling apart because of this approach.

I'm sure you have your reasons for this approach, so if you are planning on using your current implementation, I would use the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) Object. I believe you would want to use the "
markForCheck()" method of the ChangeDetectorRef, you might have to change the "changeDetection" meta property in your @Component declaration to use "ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush". I worry though that other things might go wrong due to this approach in general though.

Instead of trying to call a "Child" method from the "Parent", I would instead leverage the [@Input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child) decorator and pass the data directly from the "Parent" component into the "Child" component.

Another approach is to move your "Child" method into a Service and use an Observable in the Service. Then Subscribe to the Observable in your Child Component. A good starting point to how to do this can be found [here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services).

Also as a side note if the example you provided is really a "Child" component, I would recommend against using the "providers" meta property in your "Child". You want to use the "providers" meta property on your highest level component. Then the Child Components will be passed a reference through Dependency Inject through the Child Components constructor, details [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html). The only time you should use the "providers" meta property in a child is if you want multiple instantiations of your Service.

Comment: My actual problem is something different, I am using a kendogrid component wrapped in angular2, on a rowclick event i need to invoke this child component and i need to pass the rowID to the child component to make the services calls and...since ComponentResolver is deprecated, i couldn't figure out other possible ways to implement this due to time constraints. i do agree the approach of calling a method in childcomponent is not a good aproach. If you have a better approach of accomplishing my above requirements, then please share/provide me inputs..i would definitely like to get it implemented

Comment: Reg. using providers in child component: since I need to make a service call which is very specific to child component i have used the providers here. here I am not going to have multiple instances, but the same instance view should be refreshed with new set of data based on the row ID clicked in the kendogrid/parent.

Comment: @Krishnan - I have updated my answer to reflect the info from you comments.